# How to check if a Firebase DB node value is true using swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Firebase DB structure (see pic) which is created when a user sends a `compliment` to another user.

1. The compliment is saved under `compliments` with an auto-generated id
2. The `compliment.key` is also saved under `users-compliments`, under senderID/receiverID/then the "complimentID":"boolean" pair to indicate if it is "active"

I wish to check if an "active" compliment exists before being allowed to send another one to the same user.

But the following query results in a `null` output even though there is a child node with a value of `1`.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Query:

```
REF_USERS_COMPLIMENTS.child(currentUid).child(forId).queryEqual(toValue: "1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        print("snap: \(snapshot.value)")
    }
```

Console output:

```
snap: Optional(<null>)
```

[image]

Comment: If it's supposed to be a boolean why don't you save it as a boolean?

Comment: thanks @AndréKool I have updated the values to a boolean (true/false)

Answer (score 1):

When using `queryEqual()` you have to combine it with an `queryOrderedBy`. In your case it would be `queryOrderedByValue()` because you want to compare the value:

```
REF_USERS_COMPLIMENTS.child(currentUid).child(forId).queryOrderedByValue().queryEqual(toValue: "1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    print("snap: \(snapshot.value)")
}
```

More information about this can be found in [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data).

Comment: thanks @ AndréKool but I am still getting `null` for some reason. If I print the `snapshot` that is returned from the query it prints this to the console: `Snap (dBQd541pxlRypR7l1WT2utKVxdX3) <null>` which is the parent `key`. I want to know if any of its child nodes values are `true`.

Comment: @Roggie Unfortunatly I'm not proficient enough in swift to help you any further with that right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
REF_USERS_COMPLIMENTS.child(currentUid).child(forId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
       print("snap: \(snapshot.value)")
       if let _ = snapshot.value as? NSNull {
         // do your thing
       }
 }
```

Comment: Hey @Dani, would you mind explaining why would you recommend trying this approach? Mainly to explain for future readers :)

Comment: thanks @Dani, but as Michael said, how would this work? I wish to see if there are any child nodes under receiveID node (see pic) with a value of 1 (true). This will tell me if I can proceed to send another compliment to the same user or not.